# how to test react native app with navigation

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I've built a react native app that works (including navigation), but I'd like to set up automated testing to reduce the amount of rework I need to do in the future. I'm using jest as that seems to be the recommended approach, but it gives me an error that it can't find a navigation object.

I've read the brief documentation at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/testing/ and followed the instructions to mock gesture-handler and reanimated. Then I see that it says the best practice is not to mock navigation and to use a real navigator in tests. But the problem I'm trying to fix is that the real navigator isn't working.

App.js

```js
import 'expo-dev-client';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
import NavMenu from './screens/NavMenu';
import { AuthProvider } from './screens/auth/AuthContext';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Store from './store/Store';

console.log('application');

/**
 * 
 * Handle uncaught rejections
 */

global.ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler((error, isFatal) => {
    // Log the error or perform any necessary actions
    console.error('Unhandled promise rejection:', error);
});

function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
        <Provider store={Store}>
            <SafeAreaProvider>
                <NavMenu />
            </SafeAreaProvider>
        </Provider>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

HomeScreen

```js
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "./auth/AuthContext";
import { View, Text, Linking, FlatList, RefreshControl, Alert, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";
import axios from "axios";
import GeneralStyles from "../styles/general";
import CardStyles from "../styles/cards";
import SeriesCard from "../components/SeriesCard";
import Toast from 'react-native-simple-toast';
import { useRecentListsQuery } from "../store/listSlice";
import { useLazyFollowingQuery } from "../store/followSlice";

export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
    const isFocused = useIsFocused();
    const { user, setUserData } = useContext(AuthContext);

    console.log('home screen');

    /**
     * manage screen refresh
     */

    const [ refreshing, setRefreshing ] = useState(false);
    
    const onRefresh = React.useCallback(() => {
        setRefreshing(true);
        refetchRecent();
        setTimeout(() => {
          setRefreshing(false);
        }, 2000);
      }, []);

    /**
     * manage session data
     */

    useEffect(() => {
        // when the home screen is given focus, refresh the token
        // if the token is found but has expired, open the login screen
        // this might not catch every use case, but it's a good start
        if (isFocused) {
            console.log('checking login status');
            console.log('user', user);
            console.log('loaded token', axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']);
            console.log('server', axios.defaults.baseURL);
            if (user === null) {
                 // no user data - ignore
            } else {
                AsyncStorage.getItem('csrfToken')
                    .then((csrfToken) => {
                        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${csrfToken}`;
            
                        // send keepalive to server - if the token is valid it will extend the expiry. if not, it will return an error
                        axios.post('/api/keepalive', {})
                            .then((response) => { 
                                // to avoid continuous loop, only update if user has changed
                                if (user.id !== response.data.id) {
                                    setUserData(response.data);
                                }
                                // fetchMyRecent();
                            })
                            .catch((error) => { // token expired - login
                                navigation.navigate('Login');
                            });
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log('there is no token');
                        // no user data
                    });
            }
        }
    }, [isFocused, user]);

    /**
     * get recently updated lists
     */

    const {
            data: recent = [],
            isLoading: isLoadingRecent,
            refetch: refetchRecent,
            isFetching: isFetchingRecent,
            isSuccess: isSuccessRecent,
            isError: isErrorRecent,
            error: errorRecent,
        } = useRecentListsQuery();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isLoadingRecent) {
            // Toast.show('Loading recent lists...');
            console.log('loading recent lists');
        } else if (isSuccessRecent) {
            // setLists(recent);
            console.log('got recent lists', recent);
        } else if (isErrorRecent) {
            Alert.alert('Loading Lists Failed', 'Please try again later. If the problem persists, please contact support');
            console.log('error loading recent lists', errorRecent);
        }
    }, [isLoadingRecent, isSuccessRecent, isErrorRecent, errorRecent]);
     
    return (
        <View style={GeneralStyles.screen}>
            {isFetchingRecent &&
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#3b82f6"/>
            }
            <FlatList
                data={ recent }
                refreshControl={
                    <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
                }
                ListHeaderComponent={
                    <View style={CardStyles.card}>
                        <View>
                            <Text style={GeneralStyles.text}>
                                All book data is provided by 
                                <Text style={GeneralStyles.link} onPress={() => Linking.openURL('http://openlibrary.org')}> openlibrary.org</Text>
                                .
                            </Text>
                            <Text style={GeneralStyles.text}>
                                You can search by 
                                <Text style={GeneralStyles.link} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SearchSeries')}> list name </Text> 
                                or you can search for all lists containing a specific 
                                <Text style={GeneralStyles.link} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Books')}> book</Text>
                                .
                            </Text>
                            <Text style={GeneralStyles.text}>Log in to create your own lists or track your progress through lists made by others.</Text>
                            <Text style={GeneralStyles.text}>Here are the most recently updated lists.</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                }
                keyExtractor={(item) => {
                    return (item.id.toString())
                }}
                renderItem={({ item}) => (
                    <SeriesCard
                        series={item}
                        user={user !== null ? user.id : 0}
                    />
                )}
                ListEmptyComponent={<Text style={GeneralStyles.title}>No recent lists found</Text>}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

HomeScreen.test.js

```js
import React from "react";
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import HomeScreen from '../HomeScreen';


test('renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<HomeScreen />).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

I'm getting the following error.

```
 FAIL  screens/__tests__/HomeScreen.test.js
  ● Console

    console.error
      The above error occurred in the <HomeScreen> component:
      
          at navigation (/home/mag/code/nativeReadingOrder/screens/HomeScreen.js:14:38)
      
      Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
      Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

      5 |
      6 | test('renders correctly', () => {
    > 7 |     const tree = renderer.create(<HomeScreen />).toJSON();
        |                           ^
      8 |     expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
      9 | });
...
  ● renders correctly

    Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside NavigationContainer?

      13 |
      14 | export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
    > 15 |     const isFocused = useIsFocused();
         |                                   ^
      16 |     const { user, setUserData } = useContext(AuthContext);
      17 |
      18 |     console.log('home screen');
```

This seems to say that the navigator I'm using isn't working. How can I test my app without removing navigation? Or is the idea to remove it for testing?